# How to add hosts to Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hosts-file

I have been trying to add a host to my Windows 10 laptop. I found sites like: https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/modify-your-hosts-file/ and http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/ and https://www.petri.com/easily-edit-hosts-file-windows-10.

Near as I can tell, they all lie. The only thing I can figure was that Windows 10 behaved differently at one time, but now I can't seem to add entries to the hosts file no matter what I do. It simply won't let me change the hosts file.

I can open the file in notepad, but can't replace the default one.

How do you add hosts with Windows 10?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "can't seem to add entries"? (File won't open? Edited file won't save? Saved file keeps mysteriously reverting? Or the added names not actually working in other software?) Also, what exact content are you adding to the file?

Comment: @grawity Thanks, i should have clarified. Edited the answer. I am adding a host entry for my test server.

Comment: Be aware some antivirus programs prevent editing of the host file to prevent hijacking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running webroot on my computer, which prevented me from editing the hosts file.

I went into webroot's shields configuration and turned off protection for the hosts file. I then edited the hosts file and turned it back on.

I found this information here: https://community.webroot.com/t5/Webroot-SecureAnywhere-Internet/Updating-HOSTS-file/td-p/81679

Thanks to @keltari for suggesting checking the anti-virus.

Answer (score 0):

You must:

- have administrator rights;
- copy the HOSTS file to your desktop;
- edit it;
- copy it back to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\ ;
- confirm the operation in the UAC dialog

Because of the folder location, I don't think launching an editor with admin rights will allow you to then open and edit it in place. I tried and failed to do that years ago and I presume Win 10 is the same in that regard. The extra steps I mention above got the job done and I didn't ever research further.